# Return default data even if no record in mysql table

Tags: mysql, select

**Using MySql:**

The query results will be used at webclient for chart

**Table: tblActivity**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |Activityname |state [state is boolean will have 1 or 0] 
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | activity1   |  1                                     |
| 1 | activity1   |  0                                     |
| 2 | activity2   |  1                                     |        
| 2 | activity2   |  0                                     | 
| 3 | activity3   |  0                                     | 
| 1 | activity1   |  1                                     |
| 2 | activity2   |  0                                     |  
| 4 | activity4   |  1                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Select Query**

```
 select id, Activityname, state, count(*) as activitycount 
 from tblActivity
 group by id,state
```

**Current Output**

```
 +--------------------------------------+
 |id |Activityname |state |activitycount|
 +--------------------------------------+
 |1  |activity1    | 1    |  2          |
 |1  |activity1    | 0    |  1          | 
 |2  |activity2    | 1    |  1          | 
 |3  |activity2    | 0    |  2          |
 |3  |activity3    | 0    |  1          |
 +--------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
 +--------------------------------------+
 |id |Activityname |state |activitycount|
 +--------------------------------------+
 |1  |activity1    | 1    |  2          |
 |1  |activity1    | 0    |  1          |
 |2  |activity2    | 1    |  1          | 
 |2  |activity2    | 0    |  2          |
 |3  |activity3    | 1    |  0 [need]   |
 |3  |activity3    | 0    |  1          |
 |4  |activity3    | 1    |  1          |
 |4  |activity3    | 0    |  0 [need]   |
 +--------------------------------------+
```

so, I want to return a row even though there is no data for attribute **state** for particular **activity**

I tried with IFNULL, COLEASE etc. but cannot find optimum solution.

Comment: how do you expect to create the rows that are not present?

Comment: @Blip I am not expecting to get it from table instead want to add manually in result set if it does not exists.

Comment: @Blip A derived table?

Comment: @Blip Yes I think derived table worked like as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'create' a derived table by selecting all the states/id/activity available and left join it to your query:

```
SELECT t2.id,t1.state,t2.activityname,count(s.activityname) as activitycount
FROM (SELECT distinct t.state FROM tblActivity t) t1
CROSS JOIN (select distinct s.id,s.activityname FROM tblActivity s) t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblActivity s
 ON(s.state = t1.state and s.activityname = t2.activityname)
GROUP BY t2.id,t1.state,t2.activityname
```

Comment: Perfect, as expected, worked like a bulls eye on very first attempt. saved my lot of time.